# is it possible to set microdata to an element that contains two pieces of information

Tags: html, search-engine, microdata

Is it possible to include
itemprop="name" and itemprop="contentURL" in the same element?

as in the example bellow :

```
    echo '<li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AudioObject" >';
    echo '  <a itemprop="name" itemprop="contentURL" href="http://wave.cat/music/'.$song['file'].'">'.$song['name'].', '.$song['artist'].'</a>';
    echo '</li>';
```

Comment: Have you checked [the standard](http://www.w3.org/TR/microdata/)?

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple itemprops like this:

```
<a itemprop="name contentURL" href="url">name</a>
```

But in this case you would set the name property with an URI value because you are in an `a` element. I'm not really sure what effect this would have.

The best way is to scope the name property around the content using an extra span element:

```
echo '<li itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AudioObject" >';
echo '  <a itemprop="contentURL" href="http://wave.cat/music/'.$song['file'].'"><span itemprop="name">'.$song['name'].', '.$song['artist'].'</span></a>';
echo '</li>';
```